# XARGS: Nesting Utilities within Utility call

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I am trying to build a YAML file for a large database by piping in a list of names to printf with xargs.

I would like to call ls in the printf command to get files specific for each name in my list, however calls to ls nested within a printf command doesn't seem to work..

The following command

```
 cat w1.nextract.list | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} printf "'{}':\n\tw1:\n\t\tanatomical_scan:\n\t\t\tAnat: $(ls $(pwd)/{})\n"
```

Just provides the following error

```
ls: cannot access '/data/raw/long/{}': No such file or directory
```

Followed by an output that looks like:

```
'149959':
    w1:
        anatomical_scan:
            Anat:
```

I'd like to be able to use the standard input to xargs to be used within the nested utility command to give me an autocompleting path to the necessary files.. i.e.)

```
'149959':
    w1:
        anatomical_scan:
            Anat: /data/raw/long/149959/test-1/test9393.txt
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `set -x` ...... just use a loop.

Comment: *shudder*. This code is so very, **very** fragile. Seriously, use a real YAML implementation, even if that means pulling in Python or such -- that way unusual/surprising names can't break it. (Since YAML is a superset of JSON, `jq` could also be used for the job).

Comment: BTW, you realize you can pass more arguments to the shell `printf` implementation than it has placeholders in the format string and it'll loop, repeating the format string per argument set? So you don't need `xargs` at all.

Comment: ...`xargs` is inherently fragile too, unless you have GNU extensions such as `-d` or `-0`; look at what your code does if you have filenames that contain literal quotes.

Comment: Charles, can you explain in more detail? What is a real YAML implementation? What makes this so fragile? I haven't worked with these type of python packages before so it's a first time approach solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone have any ideas?

A safer way that has several caveats would be:

```
% cat w1.nextract.list | \
    sed -e 's#^\(^[^/]*\)/\(.*\)$#'\''\1'\'':\n    w1:\nANA-SCAN\nANAT-PWD\1/\2#' \
        -e "s#ANAT-PWD#            Anat: `pwd`/#" \
        -e 's/ANA-SCAN/        anatomical_scan:/'
```

There are restrictions on the contents of the w1.nextract.list file:

- None of the lines may contain a hash ('#') character.
- Any other special characters on a line may be unsafe.

For testing, I created the w1.nextract.list file with one entry:

```
149959/test-1/test9393.txt
```

The resulting output is here:

```
'149959':
    w1:
        anatomical_scan:
            Anat: /data/raw/long/149959/test-1/test9393.txt
```

> Can you explain in more detail? What makes this so fragile?

Using xargs to printf results can lead to unexpected results if the input file has special characters or escape sequences. A bad actor could then modify your input file to exploit this issue. Best practice is to avoid.

Fragility comes from maintaining the w1.nextract.list file. You could auto generate the file to reduce this issue:

```
cd /data/raw/long/; find * -type f -print
```

> What is a real YAML implementation?

The **yq** command is an example YAML implementation. You could use it to craft the .yaml file.

> I haven't worked with these type of python packages before so it's a first time approach solution.

Using python, perl, or even php would allow you to craft the file without worrying about unsafe characters in the filenames.